# How can I pass an object to a stored procedure without flattening it out into an array?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have a large multidimensional Object in Oracle, and a corresponding class in Java. I'd like to pass the object to a stored procedure, and I've found a few ways to do it, but they all include the step of flattening the object out into an array, which is kind of like just passing a giant, ordered list of parameters. It would be nice if I could do it in a less error-prone way. Such as using a map of named fields.

The methods I've found so far are:

1. Create an oracle STRUCT, with the constructor that takes an Object[] containing the params.

   STRUCT oracleRecord = new STRUCT(recDescriptor, conn, recordFields);
2. Use the ORAData or SQLData interface, and flatten out the data in the callback method.

There is a second STRUCT constructor that takes a Map, but I haven't found any documentation for it and I haven't gotten it to work.

Thanks in advance, even if the answer is "Can't be done." :-)

The Java object (and its corresponding Oracle object) looks something like this, but much bigger:

```
User user = new User();
user.setActive(true);
user.setStatus(5);

ContactInfo contact = new ContactInfo();
contact.setFirstName("Bigs");
contact.setLastName("Guys");
contact.setEmailAddress(new EmailAddress("big.guy@gmail.com"));
user.setContactInfo(contact);
```

edit in answer to comment, here is the an example of what the stored procedure signature looks like

```
procedure test_proc (obj_in IN user);
```

Comment: you have to refine de data for sure, even if you want to pass an array to the record constructor. But then regarding to your error prone wonder, I don't really get it since when you prepare the procedure call from jdbc you have to name the parameters. Am I wrong?

Comment: I want to pass only one parameter to the procedure: the object. So that means that when I prepare the procedure call, there's just that one param. So actually, that's more error prone than if I just did a stored procedure that took a list of named parameters.

Comment: Take a look at [Creating and Using Custom Object Classes for Oracle Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/oraoot.htm#i1039528).